# AWS S3 storage copy functionality

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, aws-cli

How does any storage provider gives copy functionality, for instance aws S3 is giving bucket to bucket copy, where does the actual transfer of bit happens?
On executing the copy cmd using aws sdk it does wait for copy to complete but none of the bits are transferred via my machine.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy files from one S3 bucket to another ( ex - `aws s3 cp s3://bucket1 s3://bucket2`), the process of transferring data will happen in the AWS owned private networks or over the public networks (internet). Files will not get downloaded from the source S3 bucket to your computer and re-uploaded to the destination bucket from your computer.

Comment: so is aws using their own compute to do this copy? I mean the actual IO of the data

Comment: Think of S3 as a file system that is managed for you. Everything like processing, networking, storage, etc are managed by AWS. You have an api to interface with the file system (S3). When you use the aws cli to copy files between S3 buckets, you basically issue a command to the S3 api to copy files from one bucket to the other. And all the processing is done in AWS owned underlying infrastructure of the file system(S3).

To answer your question, yes, AWS use their computes for copying data.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, this really helps to understand

Comment: You are welcome! I recommend reading the docs from AWS. Most things are clearly explained in them.